# Firebase function not deployed, old version kep

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

When running `firebase deploy --only functions` the file `lib/index.js` is never updated and keeps the old version. Any idea why?
It worked the first time, but the first version of the file is kept and it never updates anymore...

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe paste the output from the deploy. Did it compile?

Comment: It compiled great, everything was green, deployment successful. I will paste the output when I am trying again.

Comment: Had the same issue, updated the `index` and `index.map` files and copied the ones in `src`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess right now: my code as an error. When I simplify the code, deployment works.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue (although using typescript), in my case what happened was:

- I added external dependencies in the `tsconfig.json`, such as `../shared`
- this changed the lib folder structure and `lib/index.js` has been moved to `lib/functions/src/index.js`
- however the `main` entry point in the `package.json` was still pointing to the old `lib/index.js` which was still there.

To fix:

- delete `lib` folder
- change the `main` entry in the `tsconfig.json` accordingly to new `lib` structure